# newtonsoft json.net skip string or integers

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

i got a little problem over here, 
i want to serialize an a Dictionary and it contains `string`,`integers`,`object`

now i am looping through the Dictionary

```
 var data ="";
 foreach (var dict in dictObject)
 {
    var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict.value, Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings()
     {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
                    {
                      new IsoDateTimeConverter(){DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"}    
                    }
      });

    data += dict.key +"="+ value;
 }
```

now i dont want the `Json.Net` to serialize the `string` , `integers` in that dictionary. because few string contains `\r\n` and the things are getting messed up in there.

so i want it to skip the `strings` and `integers`, but the dictionary may contain `DateTime` etc etc stuff. I am pointing out only string and integers as example.

dictionary contains my own custom classes , `entity classes` , `integers` , `strings` , `date time` , etc etc stuff. I just want the `JSON.NET` to serialize my own custom classes and entity classes.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dictionary before serialize it, for example by Assembly:

```
var customTypesAssembly = typeof(CustomClass).Assembly;
var filteredDictionary = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value.GetType().Assembly == customTypesAssembly)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredDictionary);
```